# Tidyverse equivalent of which()

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets say I have the following (dummy) df:

```
df <- data.frame(conference = c('East', 'East', 'East', 'West', 'West', 'East'),
                 team = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
                 points = c(11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5),
                 rebounds = c(7, 7, 6, 9, 12, 8))
```

and I want to do some math to the points and rebounds column. In base R, I could do stuff like

```r
a_val <- sum(df$points[which(df$team == "A")]) /
  sum(df$rebounds[which(df$team == "A")])
b_val <- sum(df$points[which(df$team == "B" & df$rebounds >= 7)]) /
  sum(df$rebounds[which(df$team == "B" & df$rebounds >= 7)])
```

What is the equivalent of `which()` in tidy-verse to make these kinds of operations more efficient?

Comment: There is no equivalent of which in `tidyverse`, but you can use it in `tidyverse` framework. Can you be a bit more specific as to what your expected output is?

Comment: @Maël, well the expected outputs for a_val and b_val here would be 1.45 and ~0.571 respectively. But these are just two examples. More generally, I am trying to figure out how to place multiple conditions on tidyverse.

Comment: omg this might be a breakthrough for me. you can do that!? Does it work inside of tidyverse as expected?

Comment: Thank you @G.Grothendieck can you maybe put this in an answer so I can give it the solution check mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't actually need `which` in the question's example. Without it we are left with logical indexing which works on both data frames and tibbles and gives the same answer. e.g.

```
library(tibble)

tib <- as_tibble(df)
a_val <- sum(tib$points[tib$team == "A"]) / sum(tib$rebounds[tib$team == "A"])
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest route is grouping the dataframe before doing the calculations with `summarise`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(conference = c('East', 'East', 'East', 'West', 'West', 'East'),
                 team = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
                 points = c(11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5),
                 rebounds = c(7, 7, 6, 9, 12, 8))

df |> 
  group_by(team) |> 
  summarise(a_val = sum(points)/sum(rebounds),
            b_val = sum(points[rebounds>=7])/sum(rebounds>=7))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   team  a_val b_val
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A     1.45    9.5
#> 2 B     0.571   6  
#> 3 C     0.625   5
```

Comment: Thanks @AndyBaxter. What about the second example with two conditions (i.e., [which(df$team == "B" & df$rebounds >= 7)])

Comment: @grace.cutler, likely either `group_by(df, team, over7 = rebounds >= 7) |> summarize(val = sum(points)/sum(rebounds))` (for both under and over 7) or just `filter(df, rebounds >= 7) |> group_by(team) |> summarize(val = sum(points)/sum(rebounds))` if you don't want "under 7 rebounds".

Comment: @r2evans huh, okay. So it looks like Tidyverse does not have a simple equivalent of which(), but it is possible to achieve the same effect by creating new categories within the operation. That is a little counterintuitive, but I think I understand what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: From my perspective, `which` is about as basic as you can get, there's little improving on it. I have no idea what a "better/tidyverse" version could even look like other than to `filter` or `group_by` the condition. What exactly do you mean *"simple equivalent of which()"*? Isn't it as simple as it gets? The only thing more basic would be `sum(points[rebounds>=7])/sum(rebounds>=7)`.

Comment: Have added r2evans' simple line for the extra filtering (apologies had not noticed extra conditions on first post). The tidyverse idea keeps it all in a 'tidy' dataframe. You can always either pluck single vals from there or as noted filter the dataframe to give back only the single value you need.